# Orchard. How to render something before 'HeadScripts' shape?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Sometimes javascript code needs some data from server (e.g. constants or configs shared between JS and C#). I don't want to pull this data via Ajax. I want to render this data into html page on server.

Let's say, I have a component which consits of C# server-side code and JS client-side code. Component defines some C# constants to be provided for a specific JS code. This definition can be done somehow in ResourceManifest. Defined C# constants should be rendered into html before JS script links. The first part of JS links is rendered in 'HeadScripts' shape.

The question is how to render something before 'HeadScripts' shape?

I tried to wrap 'HeadScripts' shape. But it didn't help.

Wrapper in `IShapeTableProvider` implementation:

```
builder.Describe("HeadScripts").Configure(desc => desc.Wrappers.Add("HeadScriptsWrapper"));
```

HeadScriptsWrapper.cshtml:

```
<script>
    var ServerConstants = {
        const1: 'value1',
        const2: 'value2'
    };
</script>
@Display(Model.Child)
```

The result is:

```
...
<script src="/.../jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../onemore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<meta content="Orchard" name="generator" />
<meta content="utf-8" name="charset" />
...
<link href="/.../favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<script>
    var ServerConstants = {
        const1: 'value1',
        const2: 'value2'
    };
</script>
```

As you can see code from wrapper is rendered after 'HeadScripts'.
Please help.

Comment: There are many examples throughout the code of modules initializing client-side variables for script to use. This is done with a `using(Script.AtFoot)` block. This is a much better approach than what you're asking for. The second comment I'd make is that your code should not depend on the order on the page. This is easily achieved by putting your code in a 'ready' event instead of inlining it. If you still want to output before head scripts, override document.cshtml.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Thank you for your answer. `Script.AtFoot` is an aceptable solution. I agree that JS code shouldn't rely on the order, but in project I work in there is a lot of scripts which don't use 'ready' event in class declaration (ExtJs framework). So, I thought that it would be good to add dependencies of scripts on another type of resources like server-side constants - this is a cheap solution. Overriding of document.cshtml is not acceptable, because I don't want to introduce a dependency on specific theme. So, your answer is that I can not render before 'HeadScripts'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to render custom string before 'HeadScripts' shape.

```
public class BeforeHeadScriptsShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
{
    private readonly Work<IOrchardServices> orchardServices;

    public BeforeHeadScriptsShapeProvider(Work<IOrchardServices> orchardServices)
    {
        this.orchardServices = orchardServices;
    }

    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Describe("HeadScripts")
            .OnCreated(created =>
            {
                orchardServices.Value.WorkContext.Layout.Head.Add(created.New.BeforeHeadScriptsShape());
            });
    }

    [Shape]
    public void BeforeHeadScriptsShape(HtmlHelper Html)
    {
        Html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('TEST');</script>");
    }
}
```

I can't explain this code in details, but I've found that some shapes are rendered through `TextWriter Output` parameter. But `Output` always renders after 'HeadScripts'. 'HeadScripts' (which is a set of 'Script' shapes) uses writer from `HtmlHelper Html` parameter. So, using `HtmlHelper Html` allows you to render custom content before 'HeadScripts'.